# Inequality used in the proof that functions that are harmonic in $U$ are analytic in $U$

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Evans page 32.

How is this equality obtained?

$$u(x) - \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\sum_{|\alpha|=k} \frac{D^\alpha u(x_0)(x-x_0)^\alpha}{\alpha!}$$
$$=\sum_{|\alpha|=N} \frac{D^\alpha u (x_0+t(x-x_0))(x-x_0)^\alpha}{\alpha!}$$
for some $0\leq t \leq 1$ with $t$ depending on $x$.

It is used in the proof using that harmonic functions in $U$ are analytic in $U$.

Comment: I believe this is just Taylor's Theorem with remainder.

Comment: @User8128 That does deal with all of the $k=0,\cdots,N-1$ terms, but Taylors theorem gives us some function for the $k=N$ term, and I don't know why that is this function above